# What's the normal memory usage for firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, memory

I have a freshly installed Firefox (V 21.0) on my windows7 (32 bit) machine, with the hope that it uses less memory than Chrome. I have one plugin installed (adblock plus), now I have 8 tabs open, no flash, no video or anything fancy, and it uses about 600MB memory. Is this normal? My computer only has 3G memory so there's not much to spare. I have searched this website and the answer seems diverse, I guess it depends on particular case. But I have a fresh install. If this is normal, then I have no use of it anymore.

Comment: Insane, at least in my experience.

Comment: In my experience, Chrome will be 90% of my total memory usage with ~15 tabs. I would expect a normal 5 or 6 of Facebook, Gmail (other realtime) tabs to use close to 750MB.

Comment: A bit on the high side, in my experience. A long browsing session will allow memory leaks from JavaScript to accumulate. It might be a good idea to restart once in a while.

Comment: @iamwpj - Gmail, facebook, reddit, et.al. are all essentially javascript heavy webapps, not web pages. The more involved you are in social networking and the webapp pages they load, the higher the memory usage. Using an online customer service chatbox like Zopim can bring a high-end single core, single processor XP system running Chrome to its knees and make it near unresponsive. 25 tabs of Wikipedia isn't the same thing as 5 pages of webapp running.

Answer (score 5):

Lots. The good old days of tiny apps are long over. 600MB is actually pretty good.

Both Chrome and Firefox are memory hogs, the more extensions installed and tabs you have open and the more complex each page in its respective tab is, the more memory you consume. IE's just as good at it. Given the variables mentioned, estimating how much memory each instance of Firefox you run is totally dependent on your web browsing habits.

The browser is a complete rendering environment with built-in runtime code interpreter. No matter which you run, it's memory and resource requirements are not going to shrink for the forseen future.

You'll be upgrading your computer soon to a multi-core processor, 64 bit OS and 4GB or more memory. It's getting so that running Acrobat XI is nigh impossible on the system you probably have. Also, as web applications become more widespread, expect that your system will start choking with more than 4 browser tabs open.

Answer (score 3):

run `about:memory` inside Firefox and look what is using so much RAM. My Firefox uses 350MB with 20 tabs open.

Often a broken profile is causing a higher memory usage. This can be fixed by doing a profile reset:

**Reset Firefox – easily fix most problems**

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems

[image]

[image]

Here is a blog with user quotes which also had high mem usage, which are fixed after doing the reset.

https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2013/02/22/reset-firefox-is-wonderful/

Comment: Too bad this doesn't exist for Internet Explorer. And no, the various Microsoft Fix-it's don't actually take care of the problems and therefore are not the equivalent. I'll give it a run on a day when I'm ready to rebuild my rather complex web development environment as it appears I will have to reload all the needed extensions. Chrome/Firefox for development, IE for checking the weirdness.

Comment: He mentions it is freshly installed (i.e. new profile). Not much point in doing this.